# Windows Server 2003 Synchronize Not Sticking

Tags: windows-server-2003, configuration, connection, synchronization

We have a Windows Server 2003. It had Raid running on 2 disks. One disk failed and the Raid Controller failed. We replaced the disk and controller and restored everything. No data was lost.

The users of that server found that there were a number of directories that appeared empty. We found that from their machine, we could right-click on the directory and select "Synchronize" and the files in the directory would now be visible to them.

However, when opening Internet Explorer and browsing the web and ftp'ing to a web site, the files in the directory would vanish. We would have to "Synchronize" them again to get them to reappear.

What is going on to cause this need to Synchronize and then re-Synchronize again?

What do we need to do to fix this so that the directories are permanently visible?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is a problem with the Offline Files, if a user logs on to a different workstation what do they see (new profile = new offline file store). It might be that the files are in the users local offline store and not on the server?

Comment: All users on all workstations are having the same problem.